# Spark/Scala RDD join always gives me empty result

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have been playing with Spark and I found my join operation doesn't work. Below are part of my code and result in scala console:

```
scala> val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("Part4")
scala> val sc = new SparkContext(conf)


scala> val k1 = sc.parallelize(List((1,3),(1,5),(2,4)))
k1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[24] at parallelize at <console>:29

scala> val k2 = sc.parallelize(List((1,'A'),(2,'B')))
k2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Char)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[25] at parallelize at <console>:29

scala> val k3 = k1.join(k2)
k3: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, (Int, Char))] = MapPartitionsRDD[28] at join at <console>:33

scala> k3.foreach(println)

scala> k3.collect
res33: Array[(Int, (Int, Char))] = Array()
```

So I just created a toy example with two rdd Lists k1 and k2 with (k,v) pairs and try to join them. However, the result k3 is always empty. We can see k1 and k2 are correctly specified but k3 is empty nevertheless.

What is wrong?

-------Update my question:
I think I know where the problem is but I'm still confused:

At first I wrote

```
 val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("Part4")
 val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

When I didn't have those two lines of code, my join worked but when I added those it wouldn't work.
Why was that?

Comment: which Spark version are you using? I just tried it with 1.6 and it works.

Comment: Really? I'm using 1.6. I don't know why. Let me try again.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk I restarted and tried again but still got empty result. When I typed k3.foreach(println) I saw something at the end of my console appeared for one millisecond and vanished. That seemed to be the join result but then I typed k3.collect() and still got nothing. It is very weird.

Comment: Works for me too. Maybe there are some clues in logs (debug logs)?

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto Mac Yosemite...Have no idea what happened..

Comment: Try to run a spark-submit, I hope It works properly 

Comment: When you do the `println`, maybe you just didn't notice the actual elements getting printed in between all of the log messages? The empty Array after the call to `collect` is strange, though. I'm also getting the correct result.

Comment: Try to call `collect` on `k1`, `k2`? What are the results? Try to call other methods on `k3`, any [action](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#actions).

Comment: I think I know what the weird thing is. At first I wrote  "val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("Part4")" and "val sc = new SparkContext(conf)". When I did't have those two lines of code, my join worked but it wouldn't work when I specified conf and sc in the above way.Why was that?@TonTorres

Comment: I think I know what the weird thing is. At first I wrote "val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("Part4")" and "val sc = new SparkContext(conf)". When I did't have those two lines of code, my join worked but it wouldn't work when I specified conf and sc in the above way.Why was that? @ Aviean

Comment: I think I know what the weird thing is. At first I wrote "val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("Part4")" and "val sc = new SparkContext(conf)". When I did't have those two lines of code, my join worked but it wouldn't work when I specified conf and sc in the above way.Why was that? @ Alberto Bonsanto

Comment: I can't reproduce this error first ! secondly, rdd.foreach(println) is a heresy and [here](https://www.quora.com/Apache-Spark-Why-foreach-is-called-an-action) is why !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spark-shell` starts up it own Spark Context. Alas Spark does not like multiple contexts running in the same application.  When I execute the second line (`val sc = new SparkContext(conf)`) in spark-shell I get

```
SNIP LOTS OF ERROR LINES
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). To ignore this error, set spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts = true. The currently running SparkContext was created at:
org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:82)
SNIP LOTS OF ERROR LINES
```

Spark has lots of static context and other stuff that means it does not work will when you have two contexts. I'd chalk this down to that however alas I can not prove it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did spark not complain when you created the second spark context?

Comment: Yeah I saw that complaint but I did not give enough notice. Thanks for noticing!